# Issues with breakpoints in Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, breakpoints

Alright this is a weird one. I've read through multiple other questions relating to this but nothing seems to work to fix it. Tailwind is working fine except for breakpoints.

I have this in the head

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

This is my tailwind.config (I even tried this with custom breakpoints added in here, still didn't work)

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ["./*.{html,js}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                "marine-blue": "hsl(213, 96%, 18%)",
                "purplish-blue": "hsl(243, 100%, 62%)",
                "pastel-blue": "hsl(228, 100%, 84%)",
                "light-blue": "hsl(206, 94%, 87%)",
                "strawberry-red": "hsl(354, 84%, 57%)",
                "cool-gray": "hsl(231, 11%, 63%)",
                "light-gray": "hsl(229, 24%, 87%)",
                "magnolia": "hsl(217, 100%, 97%)",
                "alabaster": "hsl(231, 100%, 99%)",
                "white": "hsl(0, 0%, 100%)",
            },
            fontFamily: {
                ubuntu: ["Ubuntu", "sans-serif"],
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

This is the base code, it works fine

```
 <div class="container w-full relative z-10">
                <img
                    src="assets/images/bg-sidebar-mobile.svg"
                    alt="sidebar image"
                    class="absolute w-full z-10 max-h-[180px]"
                />
            </div>
```

Now I can add in a hidden class and that works as well, the div disappears like expected

```
 <div class="container w-full relative z-10 hidden">
                <img
                    src="assets/images/bg-sidebar-mobile.svg"
                    alt="sidebar image"
                    class="absolute w-full z-10 max-h-[180px]"
                />
            </div>
```

This is where it stops working

```
 <div class="container w-full relative z-10 sm:hidden">
                <img
                    src="assets/images/bg-sidebar-mobile.svg"
                    alt="sidebar image"
                    class="absolute w-full z-10 max-h-[180px]"
                />
            </div>
```

This also doesn't work (div stays hidden and never switches to block)

```
  <div class="container w-full relative z-10 hidden md:block">
                <img
                    src="assets/images/bg-sidebar-mobile.svg"
                    alt="sidebar image"
                    class="absolute w-full z-10 max-h-[180px]"
                />
            </div>
```

Doesn't matter how I resize the browser/responsive window in chrome inspector, I can add xs:block sm:hidden, etc. the breakpoint code just does not work. Adding in any of the breakpoint tags (xs, sm, md, lg, xl) is not being executed for some reason. I can drop the breakpoint tag and it works fine though.

I've closed and reopened VC Code, restarted the --watch function for tailwind, tried this in both Chrome and Firefox, breakpoints just aren't working.

Comment: Could you tell me what framework do you use in your application so I can check the Tailwind configuration for it?

Comment: Just basic HTML and JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely removing Tailwind and deleting all files and code relating to Tailwind and then reinstalling it fixed the issue. No idea what actually caused it. Before removing Tailwind, I made an entirely new index.html and css files and double checked all the links and code, Tailwind still didn't work correctly until fully removing and reinstalling it.

Comment: If this is how you solved your issue please select it as the formal answer so it gets removed from the queue of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

I truly understand your plight and I'll explain how tailwind breakpoints work in simple terms.

we have a couple of breakpoints:
`xs` `sm` `md` `lg` `xl` etc.

Manually add the breakpoints to `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: "640px",
      md: "768px",
      lg: "1024px",
      xl: "1280px",
    },
  },
};
```

**Example**

```
<p class="text-md xs:text-lg sm:text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-4xl xl:text-5xl"> 
  Hello
</p>
```

In the above codeblock, we want to scale the size of `Hello` when each breakpoint hits. Also, notice that at the beginning of the utility classes we have `text-md` which serves as the default font size when we hit below `xs`.

To use this in your application and solve your current bug, you need to specify at what breakpoint you intend to display the div.

For instance, the below codeblock shows that the image will be hidden until the `xl` breakpoint is reached. It won't show on anything below `xl`

```
class="hidden xl:block"
```

**The Solution**

```
 <div class="container w-full relative z-10 hidden xl:block">
       <img
          src="assets/images/bg-sidebar-mobile.svg"
          alt="sidebar image"
          class="absolute w-full z-10 max-h-[180px]"
        />
 </div>
```

Comment: I have already tried that, which is why I'm so confused. I straight up copied and pasted your code, *hidden* works fine, but *xl:block* isn't working, which is the weird part. I can stretch the page as far as it'll go and it won't activate. I can change xl:block to sm:block (or any other breakpoint) and it still doesn't activate.

I even copied your "hello" example and just pasted it right at the top, under the body tag. text-md works, but none of the breakpoints work.

Comment: That's a bit strange. I've updated my answer. You can directly specify the breakpoints in `tailwind.config.js`

Comment: Went ahead and added that too, still nada. I did find out that the only color that works with the bg tag is red for some reason, so something is just not working with Tailwind. bg-red-500 changes the background to red, but any other color just defaults to white.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [documentation instructions for Tailwind CLI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) for a simple project with the default config and it worked. You can see the example in this [repo on my github](https://github.com/marcelofreires/stackoverflow-question-77782523). I suggest you clone the repo and follow the project instructions to see it in action.